# Implicitly loading submodules in Jenkins pipeline stages

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, git-submodules

Is there a way to modify a Jenkins pipeline script using Git repositories to automatically init submodules?

```
pipeline {
 stages {
  stage('Something A') {
    steps {
      sh 'git submodule update --init'
      // stuff
    }
  }
  stage('Something B') {
    steps {
      sh 'git submodule update --init'
      // stuff
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Should preferably be updated to something like

```
pipeline {
 options { submodule auto }
 stages {
  stage('Something A') {
    steps {
      // stuff
    }
  }
  stage('Something B') {
    steps {
      // stuff
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there an implemented way of doing this? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have been using the `git` step so far to clone a repository.

However for advanced features (like submodules) there's the `checkout` step available:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

The checkout steps provides an option to update all submodules and can even update the submodules recursively, e.g.:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: '*/master']],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
        disableSubmodules: false,
        parentCredentials: false,
        recursiveSubmodules: false,
        reference: '',
        trackingSubmodules: false
    ]],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://myserver/myrepo']]
])
```

What actually enables cloning of the submodules is the `SubmoduleOption` extension as seen in the example above.

As the syntax is - let's say - little bit more complex I recommend using the snipped generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure the pipeline SCM checkout feature to get all submodules with Jenkins project config, and leave the Jenkinsfile short. Find the Jenkins pipeline SCM configuration item `Additional Behaviors` and click the Add button, pick `Advanced sub-modules behaviors`, and in the list of options that appears, check both the option `Recursively update submodules` and the option `Use credentials from default remote of parent repository`.  I've attached a screenshot from my Jenkins (version 2.303.1) showing the list of options with the required boxes checked.

[image: screenshot of Jenkins SCM additional behaviors]